# Conditional Statements II

Tags: java, javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, acrobat

Those are the fields that I have that I want to write a conditional statement for in a PDF form that I am creating in Adobe Acrobat Pro X. In the form if I tick the checkbox I would like FP1 to get the value from QxHxW1. If the checkbox is not ticked I want FP1 to register as "0". I have been trying to do this with different tutorials that I have found online and each time I get some sort of SyntaxError.

is there anything I can do to fix this? Am I way off with the way that this is written?

FrenchPane1 is a checkbox
FP1 is a text box
QxHxW1 is a text box

Comment: ^ Preferably an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript, this would be:

```js
var check = document.getElementsByClassName('check');

for( var i = 0; i < check.length; i++ ){
  check[i].onchange = function() {
     var isChecked = this.checked;
     var target = document.querySelector(this.dataset.target);
     var source = document.querySelector(this.dataset.source);
     target.value = isChecked ? source.value : '0';
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="FrenchPane1"><input type="checkbox" id="FrenchPane1" data-target="#FP1" data-source="#QxHxW1" class="check"> FrenchPane1</label>
  <input type="text" name="FP1" id="FP1">
  <input type="text" name="QxHxW1" id="QxHxW1" value="Some values">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="FrenchPane1"><input type="checkbox" id="FrenchPane2" data-target="#FP2" data-source="#QxHxW2" class="check"> FrenchPane1</label>
  <input type="text" name="FP2" id="FP2">
  <input type="text" name="QxHxW2" id="QxHxW2" value="Some values 2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that did work. One other question. The thing is I have 14 different checkboxs all labeled FrenchPane1-14. I thought I would be able to take that snippet of code, put it in all 14 boxes, changing the looked for ID's in each however they are all still pulling from FrenchPane1. Is there anyway to fix this? I am sorry for all the confusion